# Regex to replace ASCII Octal value in string

Tags: java, regex

I have ASCII octal value say ^@. whenever I found these set of octal values in string, have to replace with ?.

```
String c= "AA^@CC; 
c = c.replaceAll("[\\x00-\\x09 | \\x0B-\\x17]", "?"); 
System.out.print(c);
```

000 is the octal value of `^@`. Expected output from the above code would be `AA?CC`.

but above code works for non-ascii character but I don't know how to replace ^@ with ?

How we can use regex here

---

I have to work on octal range. For example - any ASCII value comes within a range of 000-009 or 013-027. I have to replace with ?

Comment: Where is octal value. It is just `^` and `@` characters

Comment: Octal value of ^@ is 000

Comment: It's really unclear to me what you mean by "Octal value of ^@ is 000". Do you mean that the third character in your string is actually U+0000? (It's not that it's particularly "octal", it's just Unicode 0.

Comment: If you mean you want to replace all non-printable characters in the string with "?", that's much simpler to understand...

Comment: do you mean this `c = c.replaceAll("\\^@", "?");` ?

Comment: You can cast a decimal to a char like this. `char octo = (char) 0;`

Comment: Please see the link http://www.astrohandbook.com/files/ascii_codes.html I am taking ASCII values from here only.

Comment: Please see the edits.....

Comment: You are simply using a wrong expression here somewhere. If your string looks like `AA^@CC` then it can either be the character `^` followed by `@` or the unicode character `\u0000`. Octal is simply a representation of a number with digits in the range `0` through `7`. There is nothing octal in your question and your use of the word is merely confusing. Also, Java uses Unicode only, not ASCII, though your printout may be in ASCII.

Comment: Gosh, I got it finally. You are talking in [*caret notation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) manner but doing an ASCII-safe Regular Expression task. No, not right.

Answer (score 0):

Represented an ASCII sequence, interpreted as Octal and processed Hexadecimally... nothing more than a magic will make it to work.

What, to my understandings, you are trying to do is replacing [caret notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) with a question mark within a simple text.

If that's the case you need to work it like this:

```
\^[@-_]
```

Translating your own Regular Expression to match caret notations will result in a character class union:

```
\^[@-I[K-O]]
```

Note: you can't apply OR logic within a character class `[.. | ..]`.

Comment: "\\^[X-\\\[^-_]]" is not working for octal values 30-34 & 36-37

Comment: Because you modified the regex without being aware of what it is supposed to do.

Comment: actually you are right... I am learning regex.. Can you pls tell me where I am wrong

Comment: I am playing with different set. I know "\" and "]" are reserved character, so just wanted to play with them.